# Extraplate the Invoice Number inside a rectangle inside a PDF using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I have been working with PDF's and Python to extraplate the invoice number and date for each PDF. This invoice, however, is giving me a problem. [PDF](https://www.mediafire.com/file/y35cxh1ackabc62/page_1.pdf/file) The probelem I think is that the invoice number is located within a box, the date I can get to print, but not the invoice number. I tried to get the coordinates of this box inside the PDF, but could not and now I have run out of time. The PDF and code are located below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pdfplumber

def extract_invoice_data(pdf_path):
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        # Assuming the invoice data is on the first page
        page = pdf.pages[0]
        
        # Define the bounding box of the rectangle (you'll need to determine these values)
        # This is just an example; the actual values will depend on the layout of your PDF.
        bbox = (512, 492, 612, 792)
        
        # Crop the page to the bounding box
        cropped_page = page.crop(bbox)
        
        text = page.extract_text()
    
    # It's now a matter of finding where the invoice number and date are in the text.
    # This example assumes a very simple layout.
    
    invoice_number_label = '(\d+)-IN'
    invoice_date_label = 'Invoice Date:'

    invoice_number = None
    invoice_date = None
    
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        if invoice_number_label in line:
            invoice_number = line.split(invoice_number_label)[1].strip()
        if invoice_date_label in line:
            invoice_date = line.split(invoice_date_label)[1].strip()
    
    return invoice_number, invoice_date

# Example usage
pdf_path = 'C:/Users/gsawdy/Desktop/Results/page_1.pdf'
invoice_number, invoice_date = extract_invoice_data(pdf_path)
print(f'Invoice Number: {invoice_number}')
print(f'Invoice Date: {invoice_date}')
```

Answer (score 0):

In `if invoice_number_label in line:` you check whether there is a regular expression string in the text line, since this is impossible, the subsequent code in the statement is never executed.
If you want to use a regular expression, import the re module, compile the expression once, find the desired line using it and get the result.

```
import pdfplumber
import re

...........


    prog = re.compile('(\d+)-IN')
    invoice_date_label = 'Invoice Date:'

    invoice_number = None
    invoice_date = None

    for line in text.split('\n'):
        if invoice_number_label := prog.search(line):
            invoice_number = invoice_number_label[1]
        if invoice_date_label in line:
            invoice_date = line.split(invoice_date_label)[1].strip()

    return invoice_number, invoice_date
```

You can do without the regular expression, find the line by `Invoice No:`, and then cut off what is unnecessary.

```
.............

    invoice_number_label = 'Invoice No:'
    invoice_date_label = 'Invoice Date:'

    invoice_number = None
    invoice_date = None

    for line in text.split('\n'):
        if invoice_number_label in line:
            invoice_number = line.split(invoice_number_label)[1].strip()[:-3]
        if invoice_date_label in line:
            invoice_date = line.split(invoice_date_label)[1].strip()

    return invoice_number, invoice_date
```